# JSON.parse(str) somehow retrieved very specific information of __proto__ of original object, which is not in the JSON string(=str). How?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, prototype

In JavaScript, `JSON.parse(str);` converts a JSON string into a JavaScript Object.
What I found peculiar was, even though the JSON string does not contain any information on `__proto__` of the `Object`, `JSON.parse(str)` sometimes manages to restore the nested properties of `__proto__` property.

Example (ran directly in Brave browser's developer tools console):

```
{

    let user1 = {
      name: "John",
      surname: "Smith",
      isAdmin: false,
      "birthday": new Date(2000, 2, 3),
      "friends": [0,1,2,3]
    };

    user1.__proto__.age = 30;

    const str1 = JSON.stringify(user1, null, 2);

    user1.__proto__ = null;
    user1 = null;
    const user2 = JSON.parse(str1);

    console.log(str1);
    console.log(user2);

    const str2 = `{
      "name": "John",
      "surname": "Smith",
      "isAdmin": false,
      "birthday": "2000-03-02T15:00:00.000Z",
      "friends": [
        0,
        1,
        2,
        3
      ]
    }`;

    const user3 = JSON.parse(str2);

    console.log(user3);

}
```

Here, user1 is created with such and such properties. And then on its ****proto**** I assign age : 30 property.
From user1 I made its JSON string with `JSON.stringify`, and saved it in `str1`. Now I deleted `user1` and its `__proto__`.
Just to make sure, I print `str1` and it has **no information about `__proto__` and age:30**, as expected.
However, when I create `user2` from `str1` with `JSON.parse`, the **`__proto__`'s age:30 is revived**. How is this possible?
Now I even make the exact same JSON string with variable name str2, and create another object with str2. The result is the same. This is crazy.

Output of console.log(str1);

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "surname": "Smith",
  "isAdmin": false,
  "birthday": "2000-03-02T15:00:00.000Z",
  "friends": [
    0,
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}
```

Output of console.log(user2);

```
{name: 'John', surname: 'Smith', isAdmin: false, birthday: '2000-03-02T15:00:00.000Z', friends: Array(4)}
birthday: "2000-03-02T15:00:00.000Z"
friends: (4) [0, 1, 2, 3]
isAdmin: false
name: "John"
surname: "Smith"
[[Prototype]]: Object
age: 30
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
__proto__: (...)
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

Output of console.log(user3);

```
{name: 'John', surname: 'Smith', isAdmin: false, birthday: '2000-03-02T15:00:00.000Z', friends: Array(4)}
birthday: "2000-03-02T15:00:00.000Z"
friends: (4) [0, 1, 2, 3]
isAdmin: false
name: "John"
surname: "Smith"
[[Prototype]]: Object
age: 30
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
__proto__: (...)
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

By the way I turned the browser off and on and reran the code block to make sure it wasn't a result of some pre assigned variables. The result was the same and it (age: 30) wasn't coming from pre assigned variables or cached value whatsoever.

Also I opened a **fresh tab** and executed the following smaller code block.

```
{
    const str2 = `{
      "name": "John",
      "surname": "Smith",
      "isAdmin": false,
      "birthday": "2000-03-02T15:00:00.000Z",
      "friends": [
        0,
        1,
        2,
        3
      ]
    }`;

    const user3 = JSON.parse(str2);

    console.log(user3);
}
```

In this case, age: 30 property in the **proto** is not there, which is the original expected result to have happened with first example, at least for me.

Output with smaller code block:

```
{name: 'John', surname: 'Smith', isAdmin: false, birthday: '2000-03-02T15:00:00.000Z', friends: Array(4)}
birthday: "2000-03-02T15:00:00.000Z"
friends: (4) [0, 1, 2, 3]
isAdmin: false
name: "John"
surname: "Smith"
[[Prototype]]: Object
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
__proto__: (...)
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

Comment: `user1.__proto__.age = 30;` effectively means `Object.prototype.age = 30;`. It’s not specific to `user1` or any one object. All objects have this property from that point on.

Comment: @SebastianSimon You are right It seemed so peculiar now it's so clear. If you write the answer I will accept it. Thank you

Comment: Right and you can't over write `__proto__ ` by doing `user1.__proto__ = null;`. Try logging `user1.__proto__` after that step

Comment: @charlietfl coming from Java I must be still massively misunderstanding prototype.

Comment: You rarely ever need to use `__proto__`  in your code so you can almost just forget that it exists

Comment: What is the orthodox way to meddle with prototype? Is setting a constructor and accessing .prototype of the constructor the only correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that I misused prototype.
Correct way to delete age : 30 would be

Either

```
delete user1.__proto__.age;
```

Or

```
delete Object.prototype.age;
```

And here `user1=null` is irrelevant.

For some reason `user1.__proto__ = null` achieves nothing and it would be great if someone hints me on why

Edit: `user1.__proto__ = null` does remove **proto** of user1 but it doesn't affect Object.prototype. I think it only detaches user1 from prototype chain.

Comment: Object properties can be made to be non writeable is why `user1.__proto__ = null` doesn't work

Comment: You really shoudln't mess with ` Object.prototype` either when it's new to you. That is the master for all objects in the app . If you want to play with prototypes use  a constructor and set prototypes on the connstructor or instances